# Can getters value flow from action to dao class without passing object in struts2

Tags: struts2

I am working on struts2 application. I have getter/setter in my action class. Now, I am sending object of my action class (say Action.java) to DAO class (say Dao.java) as a parameter of some method. All is ruuning well, I am getting value of all getters in my Dao.java. Now, I want to do all this without creating and sending the object of Action.java to Dao.java.
**Simply asking, is it possible to get action class- getter methods value in Dao.java without passing the object of Action.java ?**

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to do something like that?

I suppose you are populating action fields from html form and than using this Action as a data transfer object to DAO. This is not very good design imho.

If you are searching for cleaner solution you would be better if you use **`ModelDriven`** action. Your action will implement interface `ModelDriven<YourModel>` where `YourModel` will contain all data fields. Struts2 will automatically populate fields from the html form to `YourModel`. Then you can pass `YourModel` to DAO.